# error: the server doesn't have a resource type "applications"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, google-apps-marketplace, spinnaker

I am trying to install spinnaker for GCP with existing GKE cluster, but when I ran the script, there is an error:

error: the server doesn't have a resource type "applications"

This is a new installation of Spinnaker for GCP marketplace

```
.  Checking for existing cluster gkecluster... 
.  Retrieving credentials for GKE cluster gkecluster... 
Fetching cluster endpoint and auth data.
kubeconfig entry generated for gkecluster.
.  Checking for Spinnaker application in cluster gkecluster... 
error: the server doesn't have a resource type "applications"
.  Using existing service account spinnaker-1-acc-1571723331... 
.  Assigning required roles to spinnaker-1-acc-1571723331... 
.  Using existing redis instance spinnaker-1 (10.41.198.179)... 
.  Using existing bucket gs://spinnaker-1-REDACTED... 
.  Using existing GKE cluster gkecluster... 
.  Your pre-existing cluster must have IP Aliases enabled.
```

Comment: Did you verify if your clustar has enabled the field `VPC-native (alias IP)` ? Here is [why you need that](https://cloud.google.com/docs/ci-cd/spinnaker/spinnaker-for-gcp#install_spinnaker_on_an_existing_cluster). There there are also detailed instructions on how to install Spinnaker from scratch as well as installing it on an existing cluster.

Comment: oh yes, its not enabled. thank you.

Comment: I will then post my comment as an answer. If it worked out for you, can you accept the answer so that it gets a better visibility over the community to help other users who may run into this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When [installing Spinnaker on an already existing Kubernetes cluster](https://cloud.google.com/docs/ci-cd/spinnaker/spinnaker-for-gcp#install_spinnaker_on_an_existing_cluster), bear in mind that the field `VPC-native (alias IP)` must be enabled, as mentioned in the doc:

> The cluster must have the following:
>
> - IP aliases enabled, because this uses a hosted Redis instance

The previous link also contains more useful information on how to connect to Spinnaker from scratch too.